# How can I add an animation to row added when I tap on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, animation

Here is my code, I just want to add animation for row at storyIndexRow in my tableView

```
view.tapHandle {
     if self.storyIndexRow < self.storyContents.count {
                //Add content
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                    self.messageArr.append(self.storyContents[self.storyIndexRow])
                    self.storyIndexRow += 1
                })
                
     }
}
```

Comment: Look into UIView.animate()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a `performBatchUpdates`

Not sure about the rest of your code and how that interacts, or how to reference the `tableView` within your tap function. If you are editing the data source and then reloading the `tableView` you can use something like:

```
view.tapHandle {
    if self.storyIndexRow < self.storyContents.count {
        self.messageArr.append(self.storyContents[self.storyIndexRow])
        self.storyIndexRow += 1
        tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            tableView.reloadData()
        }, completion: { (didComplete) in
            // Do anything else after animation completion here
        })
    }
}
```